# Pixastic Effect Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, pixastic

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/library/js/pixastic.custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function()    {
            $(".attachment-thumbnail").load();
        $('.attachment-thumbnail').pixastic("desaturate");
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img class="attachment-thumbnail" src="image1.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I've been working on this for almost a day and can't even get close. You can see the thumbnail images that doesn't become desaturated [here](http://mentor.com.tr/wp/?page_id=218)
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you use a debugger? Firefox' error console reports: "$ is not a function, line 40".

Answer (score 0):

You've got a JS error on line 40:

```
TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

Line 40 is:

```
$(".attachment-thumbnail").load();
```

It seems that you have troubles with jQuery (jQuery functions don't work in Chrome debugger)

Answer (score 0):

you dont have jquery core loaded dude :-)
you need to add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js ...
```

just before adding the pixastic